# Meaning of "loading a process into its address space"

Tags: process, operating-system

I'm reading about operating systems. What exactly does it mean that a process is loaded into its adress space.

I know that each process has its own adress space and that the process only sees virtual adresses.

But I have trouble with the formulation "load into the adress space". What exactly does that mean?

Does it mean that e.g. the variables used by the process are assigned certain virtual memory adresses?

Comment: There is no standard meaning. A process is created with an address space. It is not loaded into its address space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every OS supports some specific binary formats e.g. unix supports ELF and Windows EXE. when you double click the binary file, the contents from your binary stored on hard disk are loaded into process virtual address space. This is called "a process is loaded into its address space"

Comment: Okay, and what exactly happens there? I mean, strictly speaking, data is loaded into the RAM. Are the variables assigned virtual adresses?

Comment: If we go in details there are two loadable sections one for instructions called text, one for data (variables/arrays) called data. The variables are loaded in respective section of the address space usually with same name. As variables are part of data so when it is loaded, its all contents including variable are assigned addresses